# How to use two different versions of sql server in spring boot?

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot

my question is how to make spring boot works with two different versions of sql server, 2008 and 2016 specifically.

The app need to get info from 2008 sqlserver database then it processes and save it's own app data to a 2016 sql server database

The spring boot version is v2.5.5

#### Update

I made a mistake, the version of SQL Server I need to work alongside 2016 is the 2000

Answer (score 1):

Configure a data source for each of the databases. The documentation includes an example that you can refer to. Check that your JDBC driver is compatible with both SQL Server versions. When I tried to do something similar to you, but using Websphere 7 (it ran on Java 6) the available JDBC driver was only compatible with SQL Server 2008. If you run into problems then please ask a more specific question.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-access.configure-two-datasources

Comment: I already have three data sources working, the problem is to manage the two different versions of sql server, I tried with this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4/4.0 and not working, acording to this site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15 the driver must be compatible from 2008 to 2016

Comment: Based on the matrix you linked, you need jdbc driver version 6.4 (assuming you have SQL 2008sp2) which supports Java 8.
https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/6.4.0.jre8/jar

In your POM properties, set mssql-jdbc.version to 6.4.0.jre8
<mssql-jdbc.version>6.4.0.jre8</mssql-jdbc.version>

Comment: I made a mistake, the version of SQL Server I need to work alongside 2016 is the 2000 an NOT the 2008, sorry for that

Comment: That's ok, although quite surprising! Are you already reading from that server, and if so, how? I am not sure if it is possible, but have you tried loading two different drivers? One idea is to try the jTds driver for the SQL 2K version. Otherwise, you may need to reconsider your design.

Comment: I tried with the versión 1.3.1 of jtds and gets the following exception net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcurl